# Android 11 Pixel 5 Emulator with old UI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

has anyone experiences something similar and knows how to fix this? I have created a Pixel 5 emulator for Android 11 and even though the setting say that is running Android 11, AS itself says is Android 11, the UI looks too oldie.

Details:

- Running on MacbookPro 15" 2019
- Running last version of AS Bumblebee
- Android Emulator up to date
- Using Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image

[image: Please find the image attached of what it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

I found this to be happening only with the x86 image of the Android 11 emulator. Use the x86_64 image instead.